# Loop to scrape multiple elements on the same page while storing them separately

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I wish to scrape multiple product names from a single page while using `Scrapy`

```
<!-- body_text //-->

    <td width="601" valign="top">

      <table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

        <tr>

          <td><img src="images/pixel_trans.gif" border="0" alt="" width="100%" height="10"></td>

        </tr>

       <tr>

         <td class="pageHeading">Pool (Pocket Billiards) Table</td>

        </tr>

        <tr>

          <td><img src="images/pixel_trans.gif" border="0" alt="" width="100%" height="10"></td>

        </tr>

        <tr>

          <td class="main">A Victoria table is more than mere wood and slate. By paying attention to the details - the hidden differences - Victoria tables have become known name as masterpieces of original design and craftmanship, and most prestigious name in billiards.<br><br>

          

          These tables, available in two sizes  9’ X 4.5’ and 8’ X 4’, are made of frames with selected good quality solid wood and finely crafted rose wood legs with Mahagony polish.<br><br>

Slate Beds used are either Indian Bangalore Black Slate or Imported Slate. Slates are covered with worsted wool cloth optionally from Jupiter (China) or Strachan (West of England cloth, U.K.) to have proper speed, accuracy and responsiveness of the table to spin. Chrome nuts and adjusters  are used for leveling. It is surrounded with standard imported vulcanized 'L' shaped or 'V' shaped rubber cushions or Northern Cushions (Made in England) to cause billiard balls to rebound while minimizing the lose of kinetic energy.</td>

        </tr>

        

            <tr>

              <td><img src="images/pixel_trans.gif" border="0" alt="" width="100%" height="10"></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

              <td>

                <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0" class="product_box">

                  <tr>

                    <td width="50%" valign="top" class="product_name" colspan="2"><strong><a name="vs20b"></a>VS-20B</strong></td>

                  </tr>

                </table>

                <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4" width="100%" border="0" >

                  <tr>

                    <td width="60%" valign="top" class="product_text"><ul><li><strong>Size: 9&lsquo; X 4.5&lsquo;</strong></li><li>Rose Wood Legs</li><li>Mahgony Polish</li><li>S.B. Frame</li><li><strong>Bangalore Slate</strong></li><li>Standard Accessories</li></ul></td>

                    <td width="40%" align="center"><a href="javascript:popupWindow('images/products/vs-20bbig.jpg')"><img src="images/products/vs-20b.jpg" alt="VS-20B" border="0" width="250px"></a></td>

                  </tr>

                </table>

              </td>                 

            </tr>

          

            <tr>

              <td><img src="images/pixel_trans.gif" border="0" alt="" width="100%" height="10"></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

              <td>

                <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0" class="product_box">

                  <tr>

                    <td width="50%" valign="top" class="product_name" colspan="2"><strong><a name="vs20b"></a>VS-20C</strong></td>

                  </tr>

                </table>

                <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4" width="100%" border="0" >

                  <tr>

                    <td width="60%" valign="top" class="product_text"><ul><li><strong>Size: 8&lsquo; X 4&lsquo;</strong></li><li>Rose Wood Legs</li><li>Mahgony Polish</li><li>S.B. Frame</li><li><strong>Bangalore Slate</strong></li><li>Standard Accessories</li></ul></td>

                    <td width="40%" align="center"><a href="javascript:popupWindow('images/products/vs-20cbig.jpg')"><img src="images/products/vs-20c.jpg" alt="VS-20C" border="0" width="250px"></a></td>

                  </tr>

                </table>

              </td>                 

            </tr>

          

            <tr>

              <td><img src="images/pixel_trans.gif" border="0" alt="" width="100%" height="10"></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

              <td>

                <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0" class="product_box">

                  <tr>

                    <td width="50%" valign="top" class="product_name" colspan="2"><strong><a name="vs23b"></a>VS-23B</strong></td>

                  </tr>

                </table>

                <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4" width="100%" border="0" >

                  <tr>

                    <td width="60%" valign="top" class="product_text"><ul><li><strong>Size: 9&lsquo; X 4.5&lsquo;</strong></li><li>Rose Wood Legs</li><li>Mahgony Polish</li><li>S.A.L. Frame</li><li><strong>Imported Slate</strong></li><li>Standard Accessories</li></ul></td>

                    <td width="40%" align="center"><a href="javascript:popupWindow('images/products/vs-23bbig.jpg')"><img src="images/products/vs-23b.jpg" alt="VS-23B" border="0" width="250px"></a></td>

                  </tr>

                </table>

              </td>                 

            </tr>

          

            <tr>

              <td><img src="images/pixel_trans.gif" border="0" alt="" width="100%" height="10"></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

              <td>

                <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0" class="product_box">

                  <tr>

                    <td width="50%" valign="top" class="product_name" colspan="2"><strong><a name="vs23b"></a>VS-23C</strong></td>

                  </tr>

                </table>

                <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4" width="100%" border="0" >

                  <tr>

                    <td width="60%" valign="top" class="product_text"><ul><li><strong>Size: 8&lsquo; X 4&lsquo;</strong></li><li>Rose Wood Legs</li><li>Mahgony Polish</li><li>S.A.L. Frame</li><li><strong>Imported Slate</strong></li><li>Standard Accessories</li></ul></td>

                    <td width="40%" align="center"><a href="javascript:popupWindow('images/products/vs-23cbig.jpg')"><img src="images/products/vs-23c.jpg" alt="VS-23C" border="0" width="250px"></a></td>

                  </tr>

                </table>

              </td>                 

            </tr>

          

            <tr>

              <td><img src="images/pixel_trans.gif" border="0" alt="" width="100%" height="10"></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

              <td>

                <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0" class="product_box">

                  <tr>

                    <td width="50%" valign="top" class="product_name" colspan="2"><strong><a name="vs9"></a>VS-9</strong></td>

                  </tr>

                </table>

                <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4" width="100%" border="0" >

                  <tr>

                    <td width="60%" valign="top" class="product_text"><ul><li><strong>Size: 9&lsquo; X 4.5&lsquo;</strong></li><li>Auto Ball Return System</li><li>Pro Speed Cloth</li><li>American Pocket Size</li><li>Standard Accessories</li></ul></td>

                    <td width="40%" align="center"><a href="javascript:popupWindow('images/products/vs-9big.jpg')"><img src="images/products/vs-9.jpg" alt="VS-9" border="0" width="250px"></a></td>

                  </tr>

                </table>

              </td>                 

            </tr>

          

            <tr>

              <td><img src="images/pixel_trans.gif" border="0" alt="" width="100%" height="10"></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

              <td>

                <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0" class="product_box">

                  <tr>

                    <td width="50%" valign="top" class="product_name" colspan="2"><strong><a name="vs7"></a>VS-7</strong></td>

                  </tr>

                </table>

                <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4" width="100%" border="0" >

                  <tr>

                    <td width="60%" valign="top" class="product_text"><ul><li><strong>PLAYING AREA : 88" X 44"</strong></li><li><strong>OVERALL SIZE : 98"L X 54" W X 31" H</strong></li><li>Solid oak for top/brand rails, Dark cherry finish</li><li>Rams head solid rubber wood with # 6 leather drop pocket.  Easy assembly</li></ul></td>

                    <td width="40%" align="center"><a href="javascript:popupWindow('images/products/vs-7big.jpg')"><img src="images/products/vs-7.jpg" alt="VS-7" border="0" width="250px"></a></td>

                  </tr>

                </table>

              </td>                 

            </tr>

          

            <tr>

              <td><img src="images/pixel_trans.gif" border="0" alt="" width="100%" height="10"></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

              <td>

                <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0" class="product_box">

                  <tr>

                    <td width="50%" valign="top" class="product_name" colspan="2"><strong><a name="vs8"></a>VS-8/Light Oak</strong></td>

                  </tr>

                </table>

                <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4" width="100%" border="0" >

                  <tr>

                    <td width="60%" valign="top" class="product_text"><ul><li><strong>POOL TABLE : 8&lsquo; X 4&lsquo;</strong></li><li><strong>PLAYING AREA : 88" X 44"</strong></li><li><strong>OVERALL SIZE : 98" X 54"W X 31"H</strong></li><li>Solid oak for top/brand rails, Light oak finish</li><li>Rams head solid rubber wood with # 6 leather drop pocket, Easy assembly</li></ul></td>

                    <td width="40%" align="center"><a href="javascript:popupWindow('images/products/vs-8big.jpg')"><img src="images/products/vs-8.jpg" alt="VS-8/Light Oak" border="0" width="250px"></a></td>

                  </tr>

                </table>

              </td>                 

            </tr>

          

            <tr>

              <td><img src="images/pixel_trans.gif" border="0" alt="" width="100%" height="10"></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

              <td>

                <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0" class="product_box">

                  <tr>

                    <td width="50%" valign="top" class="product_name" colspan="2"><strong><a name="vs12"></a>VS-12</strong></td>

                  </tr>

                </table>

                <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4" width="100%" border="0" >

                  <tr>

                    <td width="60%" valign="top" class="product_text"><ul><li><strong>POOL TABLE : 8&lsquo; X 4&lsquo;</strong></li><li><strong>PLAYING AREA : 88" X 44"</strong></li><li><strong>OVERALL SIZE : 99-3/4"L X 55 - 3/4" W X 31" H</strong></li><li>Black laminate, pedestal legs, with drop pocket, Steel frame Easy assembly. Accessories included.</li></ul></td>

                    <td width="40%" align="center"><a href="javascript:popupWindow('images/products/vs-12big.jpg')"><img src="images/products/vs-12.jpg" alt="VS-12" border="0" width="250px"></a></td>

                  </tr>

                </table>

              </td>                 

            </tr>

          

            <tr>

              <td><img src="images/pixel_trans.gif" border="0" alt="" width="100%" height="10"></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

              <td>

                <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0" class="product_box">

                  <tr>

                    <td width="50%" valign="top" class="product_name" colspan="2"><strong><a name="vs10"></a>VS-10</strong></td>

                  </tr>

                </table>

                <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4" width="100%" border="0" >

                  <tr>

                    <td width="60%" valign="top" class="product_text"><ul><li><strong>POOL TABLE : 8&lsquo; X 4&lsquo;</strong></li><li><strong>PLAYING AREA : 88" X 44"</strong></li><li><strong>OVERALL SIZE : 98" L X 54"W X 31"H</strong></li><li>Solid oak for top/brand rails, oak finish</li><li>Rams head solid rubber wood with # 6 leather drop pocket, Easy assembly</li></ul></td>

                    <td width="40%" align="center"><a href="javascript:popupWindow('images/products/vs-10big.jpg')"><img src="images/products/vs-10.jpg" alt="VS-10" border="0" width="250px"></a></td>

                  </tr>

                </table>

              </td>                 

            </tr>

          

            <tr>

              <td><img src="images/pixel_trans.gif" border="0" alt="" width="100%" height="10"></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

              <td>

                <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0" class="product_box">

                  <tr>

                    <td width="50%" valign="top" class="product_name" colspan="2"><strong><a name="vs11"></a>VS-11</strong></td>

                  </tr>

                </table>

                <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4" width="100%" border="0" >

                  <tr>

                    <td width="60%" valign="top" class="product_text"><ul><li><strong>POOL TABLE : 8&lsquo; X 4&lsquo;</strong></li><li><strong>PLAYING AREA : 88" X 44"</strong></li><li><strong>OVERALL SIZE : 100" X 56"</strong></li><li>Solid wood for top/brand rails</li><li>Mahogany finish</li><li>Rams head solid rubber with # 6 leather drop pocket</li></ul></td>

                    <td width="40%" align="center"><a href="javascript:popupWindow('images/products/vs-11big.jpg')"><img src="images/products/vs-11.jpg" alt="VS-11" border="0" width="250px"></a></td>

                  </tr>

                </table>

              </td>                 

            </tr>

          

            <tr>

              <td><img src="images/pixel_trans.gif" border="0" alt="" width="100%" height="10"></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

              <td>

                <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0" class="product_box">

                  <tr>

                    <td width="50%" valign="top" class="product_name" colspan="2"><strong><a name="vs13"></a>VS-13</strong></td>

                  </tr>

                </table>

                <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4" width="100%" border="0" >

                  <tr>

                    <td width="60%" valign="top" class="product_text"><ul><li><strong>POOL TABLE : 8&lsquo; X 4&lsquo;</strong></li><li><strong>PLAYING AREA : 88" X 44"</strong></li><li><strong>OVERALL SIZE : 100" X 56"</strong></li><li>Solid wood for top/brand rails,</li><li>Dark cherry finish</li><li>Rams head solid rubber wood<br />
<br />
with # 6 leather drop pocket</li></ul></td>

                    <td width="40%" align="center"><a href="javascript:popupWindow('images/products/vs-13big.jpg')"><img src="images/products/vs-13.jpg" alt="VS-13" border="0" width="250px"></a></td>

                  </tr>

                </table>

              </td>                 

            </tr>

          
            <tr>

          <td><img src="images/pixel_trans.gif" border="0" alt="" width="100%" height="10"></td>

        </tr>

        <tr>

          <td>

            <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0">

              <tr>

                <td width="50%" valign="top" class="product_name1" colspan="2"><strong>Standard Accessories for Pool</strong></td>

              </tr>

            </table>

            <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4" width="100%" border="0" class="product_box1">

              <tr>

                <td width="50%" valign="top" class="product_text">

                <ul>

                  <li>Aramith Pool Ball 2.1/4" or 2.1/16"</li>

                  <li>Table Brush</li>

                  <li>60" Rest Stick C/W Brass Cross Head Rest</li>

                  <li>Wall Cue Rack</li>

                </ul></td>

                <td width="50%" valign="top" class="product_text">

                <ul>

                  <li>Plastic Triangle</li>

                  <li>Triangle Chalk X 12 Pcs.</li>

                  <li>Pool House Cue X 4 Pcs.</li>

                  <li>Table Cover</li>

                  <li>Round Type Lamp Shade X 2 Pcs.</li>

                </ul></td>

              </tr>

            </table>

          </td>                 

        </tr>

    </table></td>

<!-- body_text_eof //-->

     <td width="45" valign="top">

      <table border="0" width="45" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

<!-- right_navigation //-->
```

As you can see from the code, the are fields which I want to *scrape*_ which are at the xpath:  `td[@class='product_name']/strong/a/@name`

I also need to pull the images as well from this xpath: `rd[@align='center']/a/img/@src`

I'm exporting my data in CSV and Currently my scraper stores all the product names in one cell. I'm trying to make it such that it stores each product name and the image URL individually in a single cell in my CSV.

I tried using a loop for this but can't make it to work
My Code:

```
  def parse(self, response):
   hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)  
   titles = hxs.select("//head")
   items = []
   item = item()
   
   for i in range(0,5):
     
     item ["productname"] = titles.select("//td[@class='product_name'][i]/strong").extract()
     item ["imgurl"] = titles.select("//td[@align='center'][i]/a/img/@src").extract()
     
     
     items.append(item)
     return(items)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
names = hxs.xpath('//td[@class="product_name"]/strong/text()')
imageurls = hxs.xpath('//tr/td[@align="center"]/a/img/@src')
for name, url in zip(names, imageurls):
    item["productname"] = name
    item["imgurl"] = url
    yield item
```

Simplest way of doing it since the order of the names and image urls would correspond with each other when they are extracted.

Comment: Hey, I tried using your code, however it only extracts the first occurrence of the product name and stores it twice. The page i'm running it on has around 50 for both the image and the product name.

Is there any way I can it get to scrape multiple elements as single iterations ?

Comment: I based my answer on the snippet that you wrote. If you could edit it and paste a complete snippet of a single item I could fix it. Or what you can do you could just loop through `for name, url in zip(hxs.xpath("//td[@class='product_name']/strong/text()"), hxs.xpath("//td[@align='center']/a/img/@src")):`

Comment: It still returns just the first value. Nothing more.

Comment: @user3283647, use yield instead of return.

Comment: A final query, How do I extract all the text which is under the xpath //tr/td[@class="product_text"]/ul/li/strong ? Here as you can see everything which falls under the "product_text" will need to be extracted on each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to select the elements one by one (by changing the *i* index in a loop as you did). The path expression below:

```
//td[@class='product_name']/strong/a/@name
```

already returns a node-set containing *two* items. You just have to loop over the elements that were returned to extract each attribute string.

As for the second expression:

```
//td[@align='center']/a/img/@src
```

there is only *one* match and you could extract the string directly.

Comment: Hey,

The entire code has around 50 matches for each .

Is there any way I can run one loop to extract both together ?